# how to set relevent foreign key django in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to submit a video section-wise. I create `SectionVideo` When I want to create a `Video` I want to set my `Course` *name* by default and want to show a relevant `Section`.

Course

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = False,unique = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = False , unique = True)
```

Section:

```py
class SectionVideo(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = False )
    serial_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

Video:

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    section_video = models.ForeignKey(SectionVideo , null = False , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    video_description = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , null = True)
```

How can I make my create form for `Video` model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the course(id) and the section(id) from a user.

**Option 1.** A user can select a course and a section in forms.

**forms.py**

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Course, SectionVideo, Video

class VideoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['section_video', 'course', 'title', 'video_description']
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Course, SectionVideo, Video
from .forms import VideoForm
from django.forms import modelform_factory

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # Both forms are functionally identical.
    form = modelform_factory(Video, fields=('section_video', 'course', 'title', 'video_description'))
    # form = VideoForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/form.html', {'form': form})
```

**Option 2.** Getting the course(id) and the section(id) via video creating process, and assigning that parameters to form using initial

**urls.py**

If you get parameters from query, you don't need urls.py.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from zayed import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('zayed/<int:course_id>/<int:section_video_id>/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Course, SectionVideo, Video
from .forms import VideoForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request, course_id, section_video_id):
    form = VideoForm(initial={'course':course_id, 'section_video': section_video_id})
    return render(request, 'templates/form.html', {'form': form})
```